# Python function for creating an hourly time series from a bunch of dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I have data in the form of

```
         org    area   date        sales
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   120
         abc    NY     01/13/2020   220
         abc    NY     01/20/2020   210
         ...
         abc    NY     07/20/2020   123
         xyz    OR     01/06/2020   121
         xyz    OR     01/13/2020   200
         ...
         xyz    OR     07/20/2020   223
```

and so on..

I want to create an hourly time series out of this such as

```
         org    area   date        hour     sales
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   0        120
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   1        120
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   2        120 
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   3        120  
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   4        120
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   5        120
         ....
         abc    NY     01/06/2020   23       120
         abc    NY     01/07/2020   0        120
         abc    NY     01/07/2020   1        120
         ...
         abc    NY     07/20/2020   23       111
         xyz    OR     01/06/2020   1        120
         xyz    OR     01/06/2020   2        120
         ...
         xyz    OR     07/20/2020   23        120
```

and so on...

I need to do this for several groups of org and area between 01/06/2020 and 07/20/2020

I tried the code a.set_index('date').groupby('org','area').resample('W', how='sum')
but looks like I am doing it wrong

Comment: Your input data does not include 01/07. Is the goal to fill in the missing dates then cross join 24 hours?

Comment: yes. I want to create an hourly time series out of this data using just org area and date and join back to the original data to pull the sales.

Answer (score 1):

Find the minimum and maximum values for each organization and area, and
Creates an empty data frame and combines it into a data frame of the final system. Combines the original data frame with the combined data frame. Post-processing is done by renaming and deleting columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
org area date sales
abc NY 01/06/2020 120
abc NY 01/13/2020 220
abc NY 01/20/2020 210
abc NY 07/20/2020 123
xyz OR 01/06/2020 121
xyz OR 01/13/2020 200
xyz OR 07/20/2020 223
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
date_maxmin = df.groupby(['org','area']).agg(min=('date','min'), max=('date','max'))

date_maxmin.reset_index(inplace=True)

df_all = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=['org','area','date'])
for index,row in date_maxmin.iterrows():
    #print(row[2], row[3])
    date_rng = pd.date_range(row[2], row[3], freq='1H')
    l = len(date_rng)
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({'org':[row[0]]*l, 'area':[row[1]]*l, 'date':date_rng})
    df_all = df_all.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)

df_all['hour'] = df_all['date'].dt.hour
df_all['date'] = df_all['date'].dt.date
df_all = pd.concat([df_all,df], keys=['org','area','date'], join='outer', axis=1)
df_all.columns = ['org','area','date','hour','tmp_org','tmp_area','tmp_date','sales']
df_all.drop(['tmp_org','tmp_area','tmp_date'], axis=1, inplace=True)

df_all
    org area    date    hour    sales
0   abc NY  2020-01-06  0   120.0
1   abc NY  2020-01-06  1   220.0
2   abc NY  2020-01-06  2   210.0
3   abc NY  2020-01-06  3   123.0
4   abc NY  2020-01-06  4   121.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
9405    xyz OR  2020-07-19  20  NaN
9406    xyz OR  2020-07-19  21  NaN
9407    xyz OR  2020-07-19  22  NaN
9408    xyz OR  2020-07-19  23  NaN
9409    xyz OR  2020-07-20  0   NaN
9410 rows × 5 columns
```

Find the minimum and maximum values for each organization and area, and
Create an empty data frame and combine it into a data frame of the final system.

```
date_maxmin
    org area    min max
0   abc NY  01/06/2020  07/20/2020
1   xyz OR  01/06/2020  07/20/2020
```

Comment: Thanks! My org and area has more than one values. How do I edit the step 'org':['abc']*l, 'area':['NY']*l to account for this?

Comment: Please update the sample data with your data specifications. I may not be able to do it.